# how I obtain only two attribute of my class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, hibernate-jpa

I have a problem with the controller, it is returning the whole User Instance while I only need to return attribute which are : "email" and "password".

The problem exists in the `public String login ()` method in the Controller class `AuthController` (you will find the comment mentioning it on the right line)

**Controller**

```
package com.springboot.encuentas.controlador;

import com.springboot.encuentas.library.Encrypt;
import com.springboot.encuentas.model.User;
import com.springboot.encuentas.repository.UserRepository;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

/**
 *
 * @author alfonso
 */
@Controller
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    public UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping(value = {"/signup"})
    public String signup(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "signup";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = {"/signup"})
    @Transactional
    public String signup(@Valid User user, BindingResult result, Model model, HttpSession session) throws Exception {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("user", user);
            return "signup";
        } else {
            List<User> userUserName = userRepository.findAll().stream()
                    .filter(u -> u.getUsername().equals(user.getUsername()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            List<User> userEmail = userRepository.findAll().stream()
                    .filter(u -> u.getEmail().equals(user.getEmail()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            if (userUserName.isEmpty()) {

                if (userEmail.isEmpty()) {
                    Date utilDate = new Date(); //Fecha Actual
                    user.setIsActiva(Boolean.TRUE);
                    user.setIsSuperuser(Boolean.FALSE);
                    user.setPassword(Encrypt.encrypt(user.getPassword()));
                    user.setDateJoined(utilDate);
                    user.setDateJoined(utilDate);
                    userRepository.save(user);

                    Object[] data = {
                        user.getEmail(),
                        user.getFirstName(),
                        user.getIsSuperuser(),
                        user.getLastName(),
                        user.getUsername()
                    };

                    session.setAttribute("usersession", data);

                    return "redirect:/main";
                } else {
                    result.rejectValue("email", "error.user", "Una cuenta existe con este correo.");
                    model.addAttribute("user", user);
                    return "signup";
                }
            } else {
                result.rejectValue("username", "error.user", "Este usuario ya existe.");
                model.addAttribute("user", user);
                return "signup";
            }
        }
    }

    @GetMapping(value = {"/login"})
    public String login(Model model, HttpSession session) {
        Object[] user = (Object[]) session.getAttribute("usersession");
        if (user != null) {
            return "main";
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("user", new User());
            return "login";
        }
    }

    @PostMapping(value = {"/login"})
    @Transactional
    public String login(@Valid User user, BindingResult result, Model model, HttpSession session) throws Exception {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("user", user); //the problem is here
            return "login";
        } else {
            List<User> userEmail = userRepository.findAll().stream()
                    .filter(u -> u.getEmail().equals(user.getEmail()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            if (userEmail.isEmpty()) {
                result.rejectValue("email", "error.user", "El email no esta registrado");
                model.addAttribute("user", user); 
                return "login";
            }
        }
        return "login";
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
package com.springboot.encuentas.repository;

import com.springboot.encuentas.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

**Class User**

```
package com.springboot.encuentas.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

/**
 *
 * @author alfonso
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema= "ventas")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "users_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "users_seq_gen", sequenceName = "users_id_seq", allocationSize=1, schema="ventas")
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank(message = "El nombre es requerido")
    private String firstName;
    @NotBlank(message = "El apellido es requerido")
    private String lastName;

    @NotBlank(message = "El email es requerido")
    private String email;

    @CreatedDate
    private Date lastLogin;
    private Boolean isActiva;
    @CreatedDate
    private Date dateJoined;

    @NotBlank(message = "La contraseña es requerida")
    private String password;

    @NotBlank(message = "El usuario es requerido")
    private String username;

    private Boolean isSuperuser;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User(Long id, String firstName, String lastName, String email, Date lastLogin, Boolean isActiva, Date dateJoined, String password, String username, Boolean isSuperuser) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.lastLogin = lastLogin;
        this.isActiva = isActiva;
        this.dateJoined = dateJoined;
        this.password = password;
        this.username = username;
        this.isSuperuser = isSuperuser;
    }



    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Date getLastLogin() {
        return lastLogin;
    }

    public void setLastLogin(Date lastLogin) {
        this.lastLogin = lastLogin;
    }

    public Boolean getIsActiva() {
        return isActiva;
    }

    public void setIsActiva(Boolean isActiva) {
        this.isActiva = isActiva;
    }

    public Date getDateJoined() {
        return dateJoined;
    }

    public void setDateJoined(Date dateJoined) {
        this.dateJoined = dateJoined;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public Boolean getIsSuperuser() {
        return isSuperuser;
    }

    public void setIsSuperuser(Boolean isSuperuser) {
        this.isSuperuser = isSuperuser;
    }   
}
```

**Login.html**

```
<div th:replace="~{layout/header :: header}"></div>
<div class="container p-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mx-auto">
            <div class="card text-center">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3> Inicio de Session </h3>
                </div>
                <img src="images/logo.png" class="mx-auto w-25" />
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form th:action="@{login}" th:object="${user}" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" th:field="*{email}" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                            <small class="form-text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}"></small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" placeholder="Contraseña" class="form-control">
                            <small class="form-text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="*{password}"></small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-block">
                                Login
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div th:replace="~{layout/footer :: footer}"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create UserDTO as follows:

```
class UserDTO{
    String email;
    String password;
    public UserDTO(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Then

```
public String login(@Valid User user, BindingResult result, Model model, HttpSession session) throws Exception {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword());
        model.addAttribute("user", userDTO);
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for that `super();` call in the ctor, and you can get rid of most of that boilerplate code with Lombok. Just use the `@Data` and `@AllArgsConstructor` annotations.

Comment: @DavidConrad - I agree. I forgot to remove `super()`. I've updated my code now. Not sure if OP is using Lombok.

Answer (score 0):

i create a new package DTO and i create a new class call it Login. That works for me!

@Controller

```
   @GetMapping(value = {"/login"})
    public String login(Model model, HttpSession session) {
        model.addAttribute("login", new Login());
        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = {"/login"})
    @Transactional
    public String LoginDto(@Valid Login login, BindingResult result, Model model, HttpSession session) throws Exception {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("login", login);
            return "login";
        } else {
            List<User> userEmail = userRepository.findAll().stream()
                    .filter(u -> u.getEmail().equals(login.getEmail()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            if (userEmail.isEmpty()) {
                result.rejectValue("email", "error.user", "El email no esta registrado");
                model.addAttribute("login", login);
                return "login";
            }
        }
        return "login";
    }
```

Login Class

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.springboot.encuentas.model.dto;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

/**
 *
 * @author alfonso
 */
public class Login {
    @NotBlank(message = "El email es requerido")
    private String email;
    @NotBlank(message = "La contraseña es requerida")
    private String password;

    public Login() {
    }

    public Login(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }


    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


}
```

login.html

```
<div th:replace="~{layout/header :: header}"></div>
<div class="container p-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mx-auto">
            <div class="card text-center">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3> Inicio de Session </h3>
                </div>
                <img src="images/logo.png" class="mx-auto w-25" />
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form th:action="@{login}" th:object="${login}" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" th:field="*{email}" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                            <small class="form-text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}"></small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" placeholder="Contraseña" class="form-control">
                            <small class="form-text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="*{password}"></small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-block">
                                Login
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div th:replace="~{layout/footer :: footer}"></div>
```